# How to simulate iPhone on desktop for React web development?

Tags: ios, reactjs, cross-platform

I'm building a React web app, and I'm trying to make it work on the iPhone. I've been using Chrome's developer tools to get the sizing, but there's an animation problem happening when I open the web app on an iPhone. The problem doesn't occur on an Android device and it doesn't show on localhost while developing.

I think I need to simulate an iPhone or connect the iPhone web console to my laptop so I can better understand the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it that you're publishing your app then viewing it on an iPhone?

Comment: Yep, that's it!

Comment: It might just be an issue with Safari since that is Apple's default browser. I would run your web app in Safari first to check if it's something with that specific browser. You can also use Xcode to simulate an iPhone but I've only used that as far as making native apps.

Comment: I checked Chrome and it's having the same issue, but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

According to my short experience in the matter, looks like you are hitting a point of divergence between Google environment and iOs environment. Check the React documents for specific systems libraries.
And for emulating for iPhone or an Apple device, you will need to run your project on iOs to be able to run an emulator.